# In R: Replacing diagonal elements of matrices using lapply

Tags: r, replace, lapply, diagonal

I want to replace the diagonal elements of matrices contains in a list.

```
w <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5)
t <- matrix(seq(1, 25, 1), 5)
s <- list(w, t)
```

If I try this, it works.

```
diag(s[[1]]) <- rep(0, 5)
diag(s[[2]]) <- rep(0,5)
```

But if I try this, I get an error message.

```
lapply(1:2, function(i){diag(s[[i]]) <- rep(0, nrow(s[[i]]))})
```

So two things are wrong.
First is the "lapply-loop". And the second is `nrow(s[[i]])`. But why. I don't 
understand this. Thanks.

Comment: A `<-` or `=` assignment returns the value being assigned, i.e. the `rep(.)` in your function. Add `return(s[[i]])` to your function.

Comment: As far as I know, `lapply` does not speed up your code, and you are not using the return values, so why not do it with a `for` loop?

Comment: @blueblob `lapply` is a more convenient way of a `for` loop as it pre-allocates all the necessary objects. If you properly pre-allocate all objects in a `for` loop, it's equivalent to what `lapply` does. See Patrick Burns' The R Inferno for a better explanation and examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
lapply(s, function(x) { diag(x) <- 0; x})
```

which is equivalent to

```
lapply(s, function(x) {
  diag(x) <- 0
  return(x)})
```

Note that this works because the anonymous function have an object to return, it is indicated after `;` or explicitly in `return(x)`

Comment: I don't understand how it works. Why is it possible not to use a comma between the last two lines?

Comment: Yo, I understand. Thank you very much for the immediate help.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `mapply`. This method would be appropriate when your diagonal dependent on another variable.

```
mapply(FUN = function(i, s) {
  diag(s) <- 0 # zero recycles, see Jilber's answer
  s
}, as.list(1:2), s, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

[[1]]
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 -1.7904313  1.3729230 -2.9166446  0.8452616
[2,] 0.4426715  0.0000000  0.6949080  0.7575147 -0.1733760
[3,] 1.1239462 -0.4743851  0.0000000  0.7562622  0.9003581
[4,] 1.0866904 -0.1133565 -0.1176390  0.0000000 -0.7320746
[5,] 0.4296460 -1.0967132 -0.9295789 -1.9490995  0.0000000

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    0   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8    0   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14    0   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20    0
```

Comment: Jilbert? you just killed my name :( Nice answer, correct my name and I'll upvote ;)

Comment: @Jilber you're focusing on the details too much. :)

Comment: @Jilber what, you don't want to be a character in a world-famous comic strip? :-)